# Tongue pull effect

Tags: xna, 2d, algorithm

I've been searching on the net for several days and can not find nothing about this effect. Even a name for this effect. I want to make a character that can use his tongue to pull objects objects it touches in the extension including the tip.

Can anyone help me with a tutorial or code, may be specifically to do this as this taut language of (image)[Froad windows phone](http://avorah.com/wp-content/plugins/rss-poster/cache/6ecb3_Froad.jpg) or the tongue of the Leon of Awesomenauts. In [the video](http://youtu.be/F_3jGTpn8-I?t=4m1s) its in use.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find an exact tutorial on this. It is basically a repeated image (base of tongue) and then the tip. It is like a snake game with a different graphic for the head.

Comment: Did you search this site? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31351/cocos2d-tongue-effect-like-in-munch-time

Comment: Byte56, I had already found this question, is almost it, but this one is referring to the pendulum and I'm wondering how to do the tongue stretching and pulling objects. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want exactly? The physics of it, drawing an infinite, high quality tongue, ... ?

Comment: Draw and collision using according 2 points, char's mount and end point. Considering char continues move, as char on video. Thanks

Comment: So... like a grappling hook that pulls objects towards the character instead of the character towards objects?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, it's likely you want an effect similar to a "snake".  Effectively, you want to break down the "tongue" into individual pieces that form a trail, much like chain-links.

The objects you'll want to create should work similar to a linked list - each node will point to potential nodes that can come before and after it.  From there, you pick some relative positions near each end of each node where they will visually connect when drawn on the screen.  You may want to have a maximum angle at which each node can bend relative to its prior node in order to make it look smooth.

From there, you can simply make a node act special if it is "the end" node, i.e. the following node it points to is null.  You can have it manipulate things in whatever manner you'd like at that point.